# Defining Custom Parameters on Eager-Loaded Elements

Tags: php, eager-loading, subquery, craftcms

I am trying to complete an eager-loading query that will pull in *all* the related fields on an Entry, even if they are disabled.

I am using this as a reference in the docs:
https://craftcms.com/docs/3.x/dev/eager-loading-elements.html#defining-custom-parameters-on-eager-loaded-elements

I wrote this:

```
$facility = Entry::find()
            ->id($entryId)
            ->with([
                ['services', {status: null}],
                ['conditions', {status: null}]
            ])
            ->status(null)
            ->one();
```

But I keep getting a syntax error

`syntax error, unexpected '{', expecting ']'`

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong and why? TIA!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Syntax incantation issue. I was trying to write a Craft query in a PHP module.
PHP doesn't want to see curly bois. The corrected code below works!

```
$facility = Entry::find()
            ->id($entryId)
            ->with([
                ['services', ['status' => null]],
                ['conditions', ['status' => null]],
            ])
            ->status(null)
            ->one();
```

Hope this helps someone in the future!